# How to specify the name of the table to be used by DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

This is a followback question from [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404786/dbcontext-doesnt-give-any-data). I was under the impression that if there're more than one table in the database, the name of the `DbSet` variable will be used to identify the table.

However in the linked question it was clear that the `DbContext` was choosing `Products` table instead of `Portfolio` table even if the name of the variable was `Portfolio`. I can still change the variable name to anything and I am still getting data.

So my question is how the tables are mapped by `DbContext`? I need to add few more tables in the project and have no idea how would I do that using a single `DbContext` object (or should I use separate `DbContext` for separate Tables in the same database)?

Comment: If you wanted the Portfolio table, why is your DBSet typed as `DbSet<Product>` instead of `DbSet<Portfolio>`?  It is the _entity type_ that is used to determine the table name, not the variable name.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway That was a misconception on my end. I was curious on how the mappings of tables are done. The answers provided the clarification.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do the following on the entity:

```
[Table("Portfolio")]
public class Product { /* ... */ }
```

By convention the table is named after the plural of the entities name.
So a `DbSet<Product>` will by default be stored / looked up in a table named `Products`.

Comment: And how to remove this default "pluralization" without the need to mark every entity with its table name?

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796543/how-do-i-singularize-my-tables-in-ef-code-first - but to give my 2 cents: As a table stores e.g. more than one product a singluar name is wrong IMO ;-)...

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Specifically:

```
[Table("Portfolio")]
class Product
{

    public string Foo{get;set;}
}
```